# Is multi lavel join possible in laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, orm

I have Article model join with User model and Comment model, Comment model join with user when I retrieve article with user and comments, it works but it wont retrieve user data who commented.

This is my code to retrieve article data

```
 $articleData = $this->article->with('user','comments')->find($id);
```

I want to retrieve article with user and comments - (with user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer for my question

```
$articleData = $this->article->with('user','comments.users')->find($id);
```

This will retrieve user data who commented on article.

Comment: Only if model relationship are define properly.